# Serverless - Service configuration is expected to be placed in a root of a service (working directory)

Tags: serverless

I have this warning on GitHub Action:

> Serverless: Deprecation warning: Service configuration is expected to be placed in a root of a service (working directory). All paths, function handlers in a configuration are > resolved against service directory".
> Starting from next major Serverless will no longer permit configurations nested in sub directories.

Does it mean I have to put *serverless.yml* (Service configuration) in the working directory?
If yes, which one is the working directory?

###### .github/workflows/deploy.yml

```yaml
service: myservice
  jobs:
    deploy:
        # other steps here #

        - name: Serverless
          uses: serverless/github-action@master
          with:
            args: deploy --config ./src/MyStuff/serverless.yml
```

I store the *serverless.yml* in that path because it is related to Stuff.
I want to use multiple *serverless.yml*.
For *AnotherStuff* I will create *src/AnotherStuff/serverless.yml* .

So, what is the error, and the right way to do it?

**[edit 21/02/2022]**
I'm using the following workaround.
In GitHub Actions I have this job step in my build:

```yaml
    - name: Serverless preparation
      run: | 
        # --config wants the serverless files in the root, so I move them there
        echo move configuration file to the root folder
        mv ./serverless/serverless.fsharp.yml ./serverless.fsharp.yml
```

Essentially, they want the file in the root folder... I put the file in the root folder.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve it?

Comment: kind of.  As a workaround in the GitHub build I move the serverles file from the current position to the root folder using a _mv_ command in a bash step. In this way I can put the serverless files where I like.

Comment: Smart! You are moving the file to the root which you want to deploy.